# Filter table with on data attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery, search, filter, attr

I am trying to filter a table based on data attribute, instead on value inside the `td` tag.

The problem is, that I can't get it to work, because I always get this error:

> **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of undefined**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var elemens = $("td")
    searchInput = $("#search")
    searchInput.on('keyup',function(){

        elemens.each(function(){

            var re = new RegExp(searchInput.val(), 'gi');
            if( $(this).data('gui').match(re) === null )
            {
                $(this).parent('tr').hide();
            }else{
                $(this).parent('tr').show();
            }

        });                
    });
});​
```

My Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/T57ba/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data attributes are on the tr not the td, also `.data()` will convert the applicable types, in this case numbers. Instead use `.attr()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var elemens = $("tr")
    searchInput = $("#search")
    searchInput.on('keyup',function(){            
        elemens.each(function(){                
            var re = new RegExp(searchInput.val(), 'gi');
            if( $(this).attr('data-gui').match(re) === null ){
                $(this).hide();
            }
            else{
                $(this).show();
            }

        });                
    });
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/T57ba/4/)

Comment: thanks, i see the mistake i made with td and tr, but what do you mean that .data() will convert types?